# Browser seems to read react JS file as HTML, not JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I'm currently working on enabling HTTPS protocol for my website. I got a ssl certificate by certbot, and made a kind of reverse proxy for blue-green deployment.
In this case, HTTP works fine. but when I'm trying to do a HTTPS, chrome console gives the error like below.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' 2.d5293d70.chunk.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' main.4ab1a00e.chunk.js:1
```

[image]

And that two files seems to actually exist, according to chrome's source tap.
I did a few search for that, and it seems that that's because browser doesn't know how to parse the JSX.
I saw some code snippets like `<script type='text/babel' src='path/to/script.js'></script>` which will parse the file as JSX.

But since I build the website with `create-react-app` and `react-scripts build`, I don't have an idea how to configure webpack manually.

Is there any way to manually declare `type='text/babel'`? Or is there any other way to fix this error?

==================================================================================

Below is some codelines which would give more sense about this article.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (Reverse Proxy)

```
upstream main {
    server <Internal-IP-to-docker-container>:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://main;

        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';

        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;

        proxy_cache off;
    }
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://main;

        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';

        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;

        proxy_cache off;
    }
}
```

PROJECT_NAME/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  backend-blue:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      args:
        ... stuff ...
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    command: gunicorn backend.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  frontend-blue:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    volumes:
      - build_folder:/frontend/build
  nginx-blue:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./webserver/nginx-proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - build_folder:/var/www/frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend-blue
      - frontend-blue
volumes:
  build_folder:
```

PROJECT_NAME/frontend/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.5-alpine3.10
USER root

RUN mkdir /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY . /frontend

RUN npm install --only=prod
RUN GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false npm run-script build
```

PROJECT_NAME/webserver/nginx-proxy.conf

```
upstream api {
    server backend-blue:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen 8081;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api$request_uri;
    }

    # ignore cache frontend
    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
      root /var/www/frontend;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

Comment: the error `Unexpected token '<' line 1` when loading JavaScript files *typically* means that you  are getting HTML instead of JavaScript.  Commonly this is a `404` or `500` document, though sometimes it can be another file like `index.html` for example, due to misconfigured routing on the server.  The first step to finding and fixing the problem would be to look at the Sources tab in the browser, and inspect the file(s) that are broken and see what content the server returned.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that! Thanks for the comment:)