# Browser seems to read JavaScript file as HTML and getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Similar to this unanswered question: [Browser seems to read react JS file as HTML, not JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66515074/browser-seems-to-read-react-js-file-as-html-not-jsx)

I have a project built with Next.js, React, and Typescript.

But now I'm trying to add some Javascript file like this `testScroll.js`:

```
function init() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    window.scrollTo(0, -1);
    console.log('scrolling')
}
init()
```

I saved this script on `public/js/testScroll.js`. And I'm trying to use it on this `index.tsx` component:

```
import { type NextPage } from "next";
import { Footer, Header, HomePageWrapper } from "~/componentsFromWebflow/homeComponents";
import Script from "next/script";
import Head from "next/head";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>Ace-it</title>
        <meta name="description" content="content" />
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" rel="preconnect" />
        <link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
        <link href="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64296e49c388ed7c157635f0/64296e49c388eda6b076360c_Faivcon%2032.svg" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/64296e49c388ed7c157635f0/64296e49c388edc81976360d_Faivcon%20256.svg" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <HomePageWrapper />
      <Footer />
      
      <Script src="./js/scrollTest.js"
        type="text/javascript"
        strategy="beforeInteractive" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I've tried all possible strategies for the `Script` tag, but none work.

The issue is that **when I load for the first time the page, it throws the following error**:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at scrollTest.js:1:1)

And certainly, if I check my Sources tab on the Explorer it looks like this:

[image]

**But after some reloads** (normally just one) it **starts to work** and shows the correct code:
[image]

Also, I have got a `middleware.ts`:

```
import { getAuth, withClerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

// Set the paths that don't require the user to be signed in
const publicPaths = ['/', '/api/stripe-webhook*', '/api/clerk-webhook*']

const isPublic = (path: string) => {
  return publicPaths.find(x =>
    path.match(new RegExp(`^${x}$`.replace('*$', '($|/)')))
  )
}

export default withClerkMiddleware((req: NextRequest) => {
  if (isPublic(req.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    return NextResponse.next()
  }

  console.log("middleware running");
  const { userId } = getAuth(req);
  if (!userId) {
    console.log('userId is null, undefined or empty');
    const indexUrl = new URL('/', req.url)
    indexUrl.searchParams.set('redirect_url', req.url)
    return NextResponse.redirect(indexUrl)
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
});

// Stop Middleware running on static files
export const config = { matcher: '/((?!_next/image|_next/static|favicon.ico).*)', };
```

Seems like if I remove the cookies from Explorer it gives me the error, still don't know why and how to fix it.

What is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: It is possible that the HTML page that is served contains an error message. Does it? Also, it is unclear what the exact difference is between the first load and a (soft) reload of the page, as far as I know there's no significant technical difference, unless you do something special in between?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with what you have given. Do you have a `middleware` somewhere?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I've added my middleware

Comment: Do you mean you are going to edit your question? Because I don't see any change as of now.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The HTML served gives only 1 error, the one I posted about: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Can you see it now?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Looking at it...

Comment: I meant that the HTML itself can contain an error message, not that interpreting the HTML as Javascript causes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error, because `"/js/scrollTest.js"` (the path for the `Script` tag) is not part of the ignored paths. So when you enter the middleware, you are returning an HTML with that `NextResponse.redirect(indexUrl)` while the browser expects a JavaScript file.

You could simply add the `js/scrollTest.js` to the config:

```js
export const config = { matcher: "/((?!_next/image|_next/static|favicon.ico|js/scrollTest.js).*)" };
```

Comment: Still the same error on first load or if I remove cookies from explorer :S

Comment: Are you sure you did exactly as I said @Lotan? Because it's working for me in my local similar project with the change I made.

Comment: Yes, 100%, I just copy pasted, what seems to work is instead of tweaking public paths, tweak the middleware config:
export const config = { matcher: '/((?!_next/image|_next/static|favicon.ico|js/scrollTest.js).*)' };

Since you pointed me to the right direction, be free to modify your answer as it reflect the correct answer to my issue ^^

Comment: Both of the two approaches are working for me. But anyways, editing the config seems more robust (being with the already ignored static files and all). I edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: and just if someone was wondering, the expesion to allow al files inside /js in public will look like:
export const config = { matcher: '/((?!_next/image|_next/static|favicon.ico|js\\/.+).*)' };